# Excel pivot table is not refreshing after the SQL view as the data source was altered

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have many pivot tables in different excel sheets connected to a single SQL view through power query. I usually refresh the data as I get latest data monthly. But this time I had to add some more tables to the existing view join clause and their corresponding columns. Now, while trying to refresh it, it gives an error as can't access it. I tried reverting back to old structure and then it was working fine again, but while adding new columns to my view, the data model is not refreshing or taking those new fields. Any help on this would be appreciated!

I tried changing the source and back to it through query editor so that it takes the new schema, still no luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.